# Convertir una cadena a decimal en VBA, pero que deje el resultado intacto

Tags: vba, visual-basic

Tengo un problema con esta parte de código, y es que quiero pasar de cadena a decimal con CDbl, pero no me saca el valor de la cadena con dos decimales cuando el último numero es un 0.

```
TotalImpuestos = CDbl("variable" * -1.00)
```

*variable* sería, en este caso, 0.10 pero podría ser cualquier número acabado en 0.

Ese trozo de código es parecido al mío, pero la función es la misma, que es escribir el contenido de una cadena a un número, en este caso lo quería con dos decimales siempre, aunque haya un 0.

Comment: entonces lo que queres no es eso.. el numero tiene los decimales que vos queres, lo que pasa es que tu representacion del mismo no los tiene, porque el sistema no va a agregar ceros al final que no le sirven para nada.. si lo que queres es mostrar esos ceros por pantalla (o donde sea), tenes que hacer un format y transformalo a una cadena con el formato que queres...